# Structure of structures

Tags: c++, data-structures, stdvector

I'm making a global struct of structures by declaring them on the header file file this:

```
const int Numberof=8;

struct FP
{
    std::string callsign;
    std::string de_airport;
    std::string ar_airport;
    std::string aircraft_type;
    int trueairspeed;
    std::vector<string> route;
    std::vector<int> FL_route;
    int current_state;
    std::string current_WP;
    std::string hour_lastWP;
    std::string next_WP;
    std::string hour_nextWP;

};


struct FP FP_list[Numberof];
```

Problem is, I defined the `Numberof` to 8 just to make it through my case. In the future that value is going to vary and i won't know its value until way later. What I'm interested in is a way of adding an instance to FP_list every time `FP_list`is called. Is there any way of doing it?

I know that making `std::vector <FP> FP_list`and then using `vector::push_back` is a solution, but since I don't know when and where my program ends I won't be able to `swap` my vector properly. Is that a problem, not calling `.swap(Numberof)`?

Edit: Oh and also, what I said about `FP_list.swap(Numberof)`  applies to my objects of structure `FP`. Will it be a problem if I don't `swap` `route` and `FL_route`?

Comment: Swap...properly? Why do you want to swap?

Comment: The last line you wrote doesn't make much sense, really. Is your code sample missing something?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to define a global set of structures that are usable throughout the duration of the plug-in. 
@MadScienceDreams Well i saw somewhere that was good pratice to call swap after finishing using the vector.

Comment: For something like this, you might need to go through the exercise of considering other container types such as deque or list.  You haven't given us enough information to understand your conundrum.  Also what do you mean by "calling FP_LIST".  FP_List is an array.  You don't call arrays, so what are you talking about?  As others have said I have no idea what and why you need to do a swap.

Comment: Oh you are referring to the swap technique to reduce the capacity.  That is not useful for a situation where you are completely finished.  Swapping a vector after removing some elements is a technique used to eliminate the excessive capacity.  For instance, say you have a vector with 20 elements.  you delete 10 elements but you still have a capacity of at least 20.  You want the capacity to be reduced to 10.  That is what the swap technique is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::vector<FP> FP_list` and then using `vector::push_back` to add elements to it. Based on the structures given, there's no need to do `swap` anywhere (or even an option to do so).

[`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) is to swap the contents of two different vectors of the same type, which you don't have.

If you read somewhere that you should use `swap` after finishing using a vector, you may have misunderstood the scenario described. I can't come up with a scenario where it would be useful off the top of my head, but it does not relate to when the program finishes (if you consider that swap just swaps the content of 2 vectors, the other vector will still be left with the data, so whether it's in the one or the other, it doesn't really matter - it still needs to be freed).

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I misunderstood the `swap` use, i thought it was like deleting the vector after you finished using it.
Thank for clearing my head guys

Comment: Yeah, there's code in `vector`'s destructor to take care of freeing the allocated memory, so it will happen when the vector is destructed (if it goes out of scope, or if there was a pointer to it which got deleted).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, `std::vector<FP> FP_list` was the solution and in the function where I fill the structures, the solution to add one element do the vector each time I call the function is:

`FP_List.push_bak(FP())`

That's exactly what i was looking for